# FirebaseAuth.getInstance() is saying that get instance isn't an available method to Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello all I'm working on a flutter project and I'm able to sign in and sign out with email using FirebaseAuth. The site docs say to grab the logged in users uid I input
`FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`
Now I've done that but I keep getting an error under the getInstance() method returning that it is not a method available to FirebaseAuth. I have imported everything the class is available but  not the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are reading the wrong docs. The [firebase_auth docs](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) says to use `FirebaseAuth.instance`

```dart
getUser() async {
   FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick thank you so much. I didn't realize I was looking at the wrong docs.